# Use an observable from within Observable constructor

Tags: rxjs, observable

I currently have a function returning an observable that looks a bit like this:

```
public foo<T>(): Observable<T> {
    // Execute some instructions X, Y and Z

    return this.http.get<T>(...);
}
```

So basically, the function executes some instructions before returning an observable that makes an http call.

My issue is that if I do something like this:

```
const x$ = foo<Type>();
```

It won't execute the http call (which is normal because I don't subscribe to the observable), however, it will execute the instructions X, Y and Z.

What I would like is to execute these instructions only when I subscribe to the observable, then emit the values from the http call. So far, what I did is:

```
public foo<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable<T>(observer => {
        // Execute some instructions X, Y and Z

        const subscription = this.http.get<T>(...).subscribe(observer);

        return { 
            unsubscribe: subscription.unsubscribe
        }
    }
}
```

Which works but I feel like something is wrong and that I could do it in a better way.

Is there some recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform your side effects using the [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) operator:

```js
public foo<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(...).pipe(
        tap(response => { 
            // Execute some instructions X, Y and Z
        })
    );
}
```

However, the above code will only execute your x, y, z AFTER the http response is received.

If you need the x, y, z to happen before the http call is made, you could do something like this:

```js
public foo<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return of(undefined).pipe(
        tap(() => { 
            // Execute some instructions X, Y and Z 
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.http.get<T>(...))
    );
}
```

Here we're using [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) to fabricate an observable that emits `undefined`, then use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to make the http call and emit the http emission.